# Accidentally flashed TWRP on both A/B partitions on Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite

Tags: twrp, partitions, ab-partition, xiaomi-mi-a2-lite

I decided to try to root my Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite. I accidentally flashed `twrp-3.2.3-0-daisy.img` on both A and B partitions. Because of that, now I can only access the TWRP menu.

I think I should download the official ROM and get its boot file, but I'm not sure and I don't want to mess it up more. I've downloaded the ROM and found this `boot.img` file.

[image].

If that's it, is it enough to flash it? And in which partition? A or B?

Comment: I own an MiA1 which also has A/B partitions. My suggestion is based on experience with this and not your device. 1. In any mess up, it's best to always flash the stock image 2. I don't know if your image is stock or not but check XDA to see if there are tools to flash. 3. You will need to flash on **both partitions** whether you are using a tool or command line. For why [see this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203499/131553) 4. You will also need to flash system not just boot because you say you *flashed* TWRP not *booted into it*

Comment: [this XDA thread can help you](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-a2/how-to/fastboot-xiaomi-mi-a2-fastboot-images-t3824849). You can search for more and study well before you act

Answer (score 1):

Find a ROM made specifically for your device on [XDA Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-a2-lite). Then use [TOOL ALL IN ONE](https://forum.xda-developers.com/mi-a2-lite/development/tool-tool-one-driversunlocktwrpfactory-t3866191) to unlock your bootloader & flash a new `boot.img` recovery & ROM.

*Warning*: unlocking the bootloader will wipe all your files. Also, make sure to flash Gapps. You can search "Open Gapps" and your OS to find the ones you need.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure about both A and B partitions. Android has several partitions (10+) for different things: system, boot, recovery, frp, nvram, etc.

TWRP is designed to overwrite only your `recovery.img`.

You need your boot image for kernel information, booting, etc. So, never overwrite your boot partition, unless you are absolutely sure it's designed exactly for your variant of the device.

You should be able to use TWRP to reinstall your `boot.img` if that was partition A or B.

However, if you've overwritten your system, you'll need a firmware update or backup to restore the stock images.

In TWRP, try to look through your partitions and their sizes in storage. For example, if your system partition only has 345kb of data (or none) on it, it's been wiped clean and needs to be reinstalled.