# Suddenly phone screens are changed and almost all apps crash

Tags: bugs

I cannot understand why, after a reboot, my phone screens changed (different app shortcuts and screens organization, etc...) and almost all my apps stopped working (crashing on launch). I also noticed that almost all my apps are requesting me permissions that I had already granted.

To give more context, I rebooted because I had just switched my SIM card and as soon as the phone was on I joined a Wi-Fi network (I had not joined one for some time, say one month). I didn't notice the change immediately after the phone reboot.

So the sequence of actions I performed before noticing something was wrong was:

- switch the SIM card
- reboot
- join the Wi-Fi network

At this point, my phone looked like someone else's phone...

I am thinking of resetting the phone to factory settings but would like to know why this happened in the first place. Does anybody have a clue of what could be the cause of it?

Comment: Just to make sure in case you perform a factory reset: BEFORE performing a factory reset open the settings -> Accounts and remove all of them, or at least the Google account. Just to make sure you are not running into the Factory Reset Protection (FRP).

Comment: Is it a [A/B device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203499/131553) and the update was applied after reboot? The update may have created the problem. If this is the case, try update to next version if available (in the hope that the problem is fixed) or switch slots and reboot to get back to earlier status. It's a possibility, no idea of probability!

Comment: @Robert I'll keep that in mind, thank you!

Comment: @beeshyams how can I tell if it's an A/B device? (it's a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge, Android 7.0)

Comment: @beeshyams I checked via `getprop ro.build.ab_update` and it doesn't look like A/B is active... but it really looks like some kind of reset took place after switching the SIM and rebooting

Comment: I don't think SIM card will make such a drastic change. Anyway, you can ask your carrier to send APN settings by SMS and re-install them or check from carrier website / internet what the  APN settings should be and verify on your device. But I doubt it would make a difference. Wifi connection won't.... I've run out of ideas and maybe someone else may suggest... All the best