# What will happen after downloading OTA in to android10 device

Tags: ota-update, aosp

I got to know how to OTA checking the new version , downloading the file.

I am queries about to know, how OTA is working after downloading the OTA firmware in device(indetail) level. I have check in google and I got overall how OTA working in top level.But I could not find in-depth. If you have any links or documents please share to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A/B (Seamless) update device questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203499/a-b-seamless-update-device-questions)

Comment: its is good.But I am trying find more in detail about android 10, Because android 10 have dynamic partitions with super.img..How it will work OTA update internally.

Comment: Edit your question to be clear about what is that you want and what you didn't find in the linked answer. BTW, did you read the Android documentation also linked in the answer? I have a feeling you didn't