# Recover data from Download/Odin Mode on phone that won't boot into Recovery?

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery, odin

Is there any way to get the data out of a Samsung phone that will boot into Odin Mode / Download Mode but won't boot into Recovery or anything else?

Comment: @alecxs Does S7 have EDL mode?  I guess not because mine is Exynos.  [This](https://www.cellebrite.com/en/topics/investigative-techniques/why-evidence-extraction-from-exynos-powered-devices-is-a-major-advantage/) says "The decrypting bootloader capability for Exynos processors enables unlocking, as well as full file system and physical extractions from popular Samsung devices."  Is there something similar I can put on my phone to dump out the internal storage?

Comment: [This](https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2018/05/demystifying-android-physical-acquisition/) says "Samsung does not use the Qualcomm EDL mode even in its Qualcomm-equipped handsets...Instead, Samsung implemented its own proprietary programming protocol called Odin. Odin can be used to read the (encrypted) content of the device. ...
For many Samsung models, one can use one of the engineering boot images leaked from Samsung or one of its service facilities...These engineering boot images are developed and signed by Samsung proper; they allow full, unrestricted access to the device storage."

Comment: you did find a useful site, thx for clarifying

Comment: So if [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/s7-edge/how-to/engboot-s7-s7-edge-qualcomm-exynos-t3531104) has ENGBOOT for S7 Exynos, then I could burn that to the phone and somehow extract the device storage from it?

Comment: members on xda claim it is not a trusted source, and it's not clear it is for exynos, but yes you can flash eng boot + twrp (odin may wipe userdata after flashing, heimdall does not) but the problem remains you probably can't boot any other than download mode. and you can't extract data in download mode, only flash ROMs. can you add picture of download mode screen?

Comment: beware the bootloader can't be downgraded, do not flash higher version of bootloader (it is the red digit on this example:  https://mobilefirmware4u.blogspot.com/2018/05/samsung-galaxy-s7-combination-rom-g930f.html) before flashing [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3333770) (does not support encryption/useless) please read about [RMM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3747535) protection (not sure if this concerns combination firmware)

Comment: @alecxs Oh, so if it won't boot into recovery, it won't boot into ENGBOOT either?  It has a "G930F" file inside, which is the Exynos variant that I have.

Comment: @alecxs Download screen: https://i.imgur.com/ZsJJ33B.jpg  (I like how the logo is burned into the screen now from sitting that way for weeks...)  :|

Comment: please try it is normal boot mode not recovery mode. the question is why it doesn't boot at all, i doubt another boot.img can fix

Comment: maybe volume and/or home buttons stuck or short circuit? or there are some broken instructions left on cache partition (failed OTA)? or data partition corrupt (broken encryption)? or empty slot (not sure it's A/B device)? or emmc wear-out?

Comment: @alecxs I don't think the buttons are broken.  I don't know about the other issues, they could be responsible.  What is "empty slot"?

Comment: you can flash cache.img and see if this fix something (that does not harm). empty slot mean no ROM installed in 2nd slot (should never happen). read more about [A/B device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203499) (idk if valid for S7)