# Android fastboot restoration points

Tags: fastboot, restore

Does Android have restore points that can be accessed via fastboot?

In Windows7 (support ended February 2020) restore points are created so the OS can revert back to last known state should anything go wrong. This revision includes settings, software, browser history, etc. This handy feature has helped me several times. Does Android have such a utility/feature where by any means (fastboot or adb) it can be rolled back to last known state? Kindly read more to understand the full situation.

My phone is stuck in fastboot. I have been doing research on how to get it out of this. The phone runs Android Go. Usually the OS updates and completes without any issues, but this time during an update the battery died and upon power up it got stuck in Fastboot mode. I understand both Fastboot and ADB have commands of their own that can be used to interact with Android OS via USB connection. I have a question that my research has NOT answered. Before I run any commands in this mode (fastboot) I want to know, is there a way to restore the device to its last stable state (ie before the failed OS update)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A/B (Seamless) update device questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/203499/a-b-seamless-update-device-questions)

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for the input.
In many ways this information helps. Now another question is how do I get out of Fastboot into the partition that had the older (working) version? According to the link if the update is 'borked' it should rollback to working build. But now it is stuck in Fastboot. How do I tell it to come out of Fastboot into the working build. Thanks in advance.

PS: Is there any pdf tutorial you can recommend to learn fastboot, adb commands?

Comment: [fastboot](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-discover-hidden-fastboot-commands) or [adb](https://www.gizmoadvices.com/fastboot-adb-commands) just some google results (haven't read)

Comment: thanks for the help @alecxs. Since I don't know what slot was active/inactive, I will go over the commands to know which one can retrieve the slot with a clean installation of the OS, then Fastboot into it (the other slot should be the one that failed). Sounds like a plan. I will endeavour to post results so others can learn as well

Comment: flash official ROM

Comment: I ran the command fastboot getvar all and the current-slot was NOT in the list output. I can see partition-size and partition-type listed for diff partitions though. My guess is the device does NOT support seamless system updates for dual slots. I tried rebooting into recovery but it takes me back to Fastboot mode. I can see recovery in the output but cannot boot into it. I can really use some useful suggestions thanks.

Comment: @alecxs I had to delete and repost an edit to my last comment (kindly take a look). Will I be able to keep my files/data if I flash the official ROM? I am keeping that as a last resort until I am sure I have exhausted ALL options. fastboot continue does NOT work for me

Comment: @alecxs I have asked another question with more details.

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228396/cant-access-recovery-partition-android-8-1-go-edition

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
fastboot --set-active=a
```

or

```
fastboot --set-active=b
```

ane one of them should work if your other slot is not corrupted

Comment: please add *fastboot continue* (or *fastboot reboot*) to your answer as well

Comment: I will NOT be able to use this since I recently found out my device does NOT support Seamless System Update.

Comment: @thinkhjj what is your phone model

Comment: @theggputest55 I have asked another question that has phone details and commands I have tried: 

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/228396/cant-access-recovery-partition-android-8-1-go-edition